# How to pass json with data to RestTemplate as if external service will do it?

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, resttemplate

I created a small Spring Boot application to gather data from the public API. Now, I created a base skeleton, I want to test `RestTemplate` `json` consumption and make a test that will mimic the behaviour of public API.

The question, how to mimic `json` consumption of `RestTemplate` in tests?

Precisely, how to `mock` `RestTemplate` in tests, so it will accept `json` from a local file?

My `Service` below:

```
@Service
public class RecordsTrackerService {
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public RecordsTrackerService(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

   public void updateRecords() {
       Object obj = restTemplate.getForObject("sample_url", Object.class);
   }
}
```

I tried searching similar questions but there is nothing I could find so far.

Comment: Maybe http://wiremock.org is what you are looking for?

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to do ? You simply want to mock the return value of `getForObject` ?

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel I don't want not `mock` `getForObject` as it is but rather accept `json` from a different source. Not sure if it makes sense for you.

Comment: No it doesn't sorry, maybe try to add a code that better expresses what you would like to do

Answer (score 0):

You can use springs MockRestServiceServer to simulate the request/response that you need. You essentially, outline to spring what the expected request is along with the expected response. Full tutorial here:

```
https://www.baeldung.com/restclienttest-in-spring-boot
```